# What is the opposite of $set in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

In a blog app, I'd like to show/hide comments of each post **inside a loop** of `posts`. I know how to show the div containing the comments by setting a `showComments` on the fly:

```
this.$set(post, 'showComments', true) ;
```

But I don't know how to hide the post's comments when the div is already open. What I tried is this:

```
 if (this.$get(post, 'showComments')==true) {
       this.$set(post, 'showComments', false) ;
      return
    }
```

The code above thoes not work and I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$get is not a function
```

So I'm wondering how can I acheive this functionaliry.

Comment: Vue.delete() is the opposite of Vue.Set() check [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply read the dynamic property and reapply the value.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      posts: [
        { content: 'Post #1' },
        { content: 'Post #2' },
        { content: 'Post #3' }
      ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleComment(post) {
      if ('showComment' in post) {
        post.showComment = !post.showComment;
      } 
      else {
        this.$set(post, 'showComment', true);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.post {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="post" v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
    {{post.content}}

    <p v-if="post.showComment">
      Hidden comments.
    </p>

    <button @click="toggleComment(post)">Toggle comment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `post` is inside a loop of `posts`. It is not defined in the data.

Comment: That should make no difference. Let me see.

Comment: Both `this.$set` and `if` are unneeded here. The whole `toggleComment(post)` should be just `post.showComment = !post.showComment`. It even could be done in `@click` without using method at all.

Comment: @Styx `Both this.$set and if are unneeded here`... Really? The `showComment` property is not initially available you know. I think you need to read the docs again.

Comment: @jom Yes, you're right. I've missed that `showComment` is nonexistent initially.

Answer (score 0):

Use property name to get property value

```
if ( typeof this.post.showComments !== 'undefined' && this.post.showComments ) {
   Vue.set(post, 'showComments', false);
   return;
}
```

Also note that you should try to avoid using `this.$set` because it was deprecated due to conflicts with other libraries. Consider using `Vue.set` instead.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: This does not work for me. Please that `post` does not have a `showComments` when it is fetched from server rendered. It is only added by $set.

Comment: Updated answer, try like this

Comment: still does not hide.

Comment: So maybe you have some errors in console or something else that I should to know?

Comment: Updated one more time, please try like this

Comment: Now I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showComments' of undefined` . Note that `post` is inside a loop. It is not defined in the data.